# how to get rss feeds for new products from magento on facebook?

Tags: facebook, magento, magento-1.6

i have enabled rss feeds from backend admin panel,

in frontend copy the url "www.mydomain.com/rss//catalog/new/store_id/1/" and paste it in facebook application graffiti to get feeds.

But what i get is the only one product feed even after adding more and more products.

I have searched alot for it but still with open hands for answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to know that having the RSS Feed is not supported but the CSV is indeed supported. In the link: https://www.facebook.com/business/a/online-sales/dynamic-product-ads?__mref=message_bubble
it shows you how to create it with a sample of the CSV File.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference